# How to clear the "Recent" tab on the "New Document" screen in Photoshop CC 2017?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

How to clear the recent "Custom" items?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having researched this, I believe it is not currently possible. Mine currently have 24 of them too so I think it just keeps growing.

I found that whole screen really slow too, and in my research to help you I found an option to return to the previous style dialogue box.

**On mac: Photoshop CC >> Preference >> General**

[image]

**And tick this box:**

[image: Legacy Help]

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to do this on Windows.
I think you should close Photoshop first, if it is open.

Replace the placeholder text with your username and go this path in the file explorer: *"C:\Users\**YOURUSERNAME**\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2017\Adobe Photoshop CC 2017 Settings"* 
Then look for a file named: **MRU New Doc Sizes**

1, If you want to remove all of the new document presets, then you can just delete this file and you are done.
2, If you want to keep some of the presets, then you need to open and edit this JSON file with a text editor.

Comment: deleting the file didnt work with CC 2018

Answer (score -2):

Yes.  These instructions work.  Make sure to close Photoshop first.  After following the instructions given above..

"C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2017\Adobe Photoshop CC 2017 Settings"

Then look for a file named: MRU New Doc Sizes... follow instructions 1 & 2 above
then on the keyboard select...

(Alt + Left Arrow), close file folder, then reopen Photoshop.