# Photoshop New Document screen

Tags: adobe-photoshop, document-setup

In the New Document screen it keeps bringing up my recent Items. How do I remove the recent items from this screen?

Comment: Try *Preferences > General > Options > Use Legacy "New Document" Interface*.

Comment: Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80768/how-to-clear-the-recent-tab-on-the-new-document-screen-in-photoshop-cc-2017

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the "Recent" tab on the "New Document" screen in Photoshop CC 2017?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80768/how-to-clear-the-recent-tab-on-the-new-document-screen-in-photoshop-cc-2017)